# Artin-Schreier Polynomial: Choosing a Modulus

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When working with an Archin-Schreir Polynomial and determining that it has no integer solutions how do you pick a modulus in which to work to look for solutions in Z/nZ?

For example, in class we did the example $$x^7-x+1$$ and after noting that there were no solutions in in the integers, my teacher gave us the hint to look for solutions mod 7. How did he chose this modulus?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. As for choosing mod $7$ with your example, I suspect it's likely your teacher used Fermat's little theorem, $x^p \equiv x \pmod p$ for all primes $p$.

Comment: So you can assign $x^7 \equiv x (mod 7)$ and he just extrapolated from this that he should use $mod 7$ because FLT "reduced" the power of 7?

Comment: it goes to $x-x+1=1$ mod 2, mod 3, or mod 7. 1 is not 0.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how your teacher is approaching & teaching you about this. However, in general, for larger powers, you can use FLT to "reduce" the power when checking using a prime modulus.

Comment: Ah okay :) Thank you for your help! I was having trouble drawing those parallels to the theorems we have already learned in class but it seems as if it wasn't as complicated reasoning as I had originally thought.

Comment: I think he chose that modulus because it’s interesting to the case of this particular polynomial.